# How to pass image from controller to jsp in Spring mvc?

Tags: image, spring-mvc, jsp

Im trying to show an image that is in my database in jsp.

I have this line in jsp where I try to show the image.

```
<img src="<c:url value='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/1'/>" class="d-block mx-auto content-justify-center" alt="not available" style="width: 440px; height: 260px;">
```

In the controller I have this funciton, it gets an image i have stored in my database as a byte[] and transforms it into an "Image".

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/images/{imageid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Image getImage(@PathVariable String imageid) throws IOException {
        byte[] image = imageService.get(Long.parseLong(imageid)).getData();
        Image im = new ImageIcon(image).getImage();
        return  im;

    }
```

When I debug "im" is shown perfectly well:
[im in debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDFaz.png)

But when I run my project the image isn't shown:
[The image is not shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNM6t.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the image src path in browser dev tool ?

Comment: The image is not in my project, I have it in a database in byte array format, so it doesn't have a src path. I am trying to get the image with the getImage function. Is this the way to do it?

Comment: This article will help you [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-return-image-file)

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem I used the link shared by Pran. Added *produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE* , * @ResponseBody *, and made it return byte[] directly.

This in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/images/{imageid}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody  byte[]  getImage(@PathVariable long imageid) throws IOException {
    byte[] image = employeeService.getImage(imageid);

    return  image;

}
```

This in the .jsp:

```
<img class="rounded-circle" src="<c:out value='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/${user.id}'/>" alt="Profile Photo"></a>
```